# Git push from fork master into remote upstream branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

I have a rather simple problem, but I can't figure out a solution. I have forked a repository `<repo>` and introduced new features to the code. All these features are kept in the `master` branch of my fork. Now I would like to contribute my changes to the original upstream repository. I would like to `push` them into a separate new branch on the `upstream`. I'm trying to achieve it with the following command:

```
git push origin upstream:<branch>
```

The relevant parts of my Git configuration file are:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@<...>:mabalenk/<repo>.git

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge  = refs/heads/master

[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@<...>:jsmith/<repo>.git
```

I receive the following error message:

```
error: src refspec upstream does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@<...>:mabalenk/<repo>.git'
```

Comment: it's `git push RemoteName BranchName`. you of course don't want to mention `origin` if you're trying to push to `upstream`.

Comment: Correct solution to my problem is `git push upstream master:<branch>`, where `master` refers to the branch name in my fork and `<branch>` is the branch name on the original upstream repository. Attention–colon is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As underscore_d says, first you are choosing the wrong repository in your git push. You need `git push upstream` as opposed to `git push origin` in order to push content to the upstream repository.

The second problem is your refspec. Refspecs for different branch names are given as `src:dest`. So in your case you need `master:BRANCH_NAME` where `BRANCH_NAME` is the desired name of the branch you would like on upstream.

In all, the command would be: `git push upstream master:BRANCH_NAME`. You may also need to use the `--set-upstream` flag, though git will make that clear on the first call of the aforementioned command.